# Emacs Lisp: Which function called?

Tags: emacs, lisp, external-process

Is there a way to find out, what function called?

Let's say, there's a handler-function that monitors requests to an external process.  Before it processes the requests, it prints them into a log file for later inspection.

Can this function find out, by which function it got called?

Comment: Take a look at the variables `this-command` and `last-command`.

Comment: Aargh.  Yes. And documented smack in the middle of the comand loop description in the manual.  I know, I know, first do homework, then start foraging useful, certified knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**, there is no way to know which function was just called, or which function called a function that is currently being evaluated.

Consider, for example, what happens when byte-compiled code is executed: functions you see in the source code are typically absent from the byte-compiled code.

The comment about `this-command` and `last-command` is valid, but it applies only to *commands*, not functions in general. Be aware too that some functions change the value of `this-command` or `last-command`, so these do not necessarily always indicate what their names suggest.

Comment: You're right.  These variables are perfectly useless for my purpose.  I dreaded I'll have to supply the function name with every call, which feels unelegant and *will* look horrible.  Yet it doesn't seem to be a matter of choice.